# How to add an offset to a java array in JNA

Tags: java, jna, pointer-arithmetic

I have a native function like this. It's part of a proprietary DLL which I cannot modify.

```
void foo(char* src, size_t len);
```

In Java I have a normal array like this: `byte[] array = makeArray();` The array *has* to be on the heap, not in native memory, for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

If I wanted to call `foo` with the entire array, I can do it like this, and it's is working already in my software:

```
libraryWrapper.foo(array, array.length);
```

However, I want to step through this array and foo-process parts of it, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length - 10000; i += 10000)
     libraryWrapper.foo(array + i, 10000);
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of 'pointer arithmetic' using JNA, without using an intermediate `Memory` or writing another DLL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ByteBuffer.wrap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap(byte[],%20int,%20int)) with your full array.  When you pass that buffer to your native code, JNA will use the buffer's current offset to generate a native pointer into the array.

You can either wrap on each call or manipulate the buffer's offset as needed with [`.position(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position(int)).

Alternatively, pass a smaller array to your native code and then copy the results to your primary storage.

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with making a `Memory` of the entire array (using memcpy in JNA) and then creating a view on that memory with `share()` for each part I need to process. This will use a lot more memory than I hoped, but the same as your solution.

Comment: The difference between using a Java array wrapped with an NIO Buffer and `Memory` is that `Memory` moves the memory allocation entirely off-heap.  The NIO buffer _may_ do some allocation natively, but primarily its memory allocation is on the Java heap.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your problem is the input.

```
while(I have parts to process) {
     byte[] array = makeArrayPart(); //10000
     libraryWrapper.foo(array, array.length);
}
```

So you have to rewrite your `makeArray()` to return foo-processing parts.

Comment: `makeArray()` is just an example of how I might have obtained the big array. I cannot change the fact that the array starts big. If I write a `makeArrayPart()` method that takes the big array and returns a smaller array, then it will be an unacceptable performance hit (I already tried this). When I used memcpy in JNA (offset 0) and the part as big as the array itself, performance was many magnitudes faster than copying element for element in pure java (after the HotSpot compiler kicked in)

Comment: Yeap, but isn't the problem of the algorithm generating the array itself? makeArrayPart() should not copy arrays, but the algorithm (which I understand you can control) should generate chewable parts of the array. Whatever.

Comment: it IS beyond my control

Comment: So why you bother? If both inputs (the array) and processing part (foo) are out of your control, wrapping the buffer or making several foo calls wouldn't help, au contraire. 2 cents.